# mdadm inconsistency in building raid 10 group

Tags: linux, mdadm

I have a set of four NVMe-oF devices, two each from two arrays that do not offer RAID.  I want to use mdadm to create a RAID 10 array for use with databases, being careful not to put both sides of the mirror on the same array.

The man page isn't clear but some online searching found cases where mdadm processes the devices in the order listed, so basically I should run this command:

```
mdadm --verbose --create /dev/md0 -l 10 -n 4 \
 /dev/nvme0n1 /dev/nvme4n1 \
 /dev/nvme2n1 /dev/nvme6n1
```

However, inspecting the new array shows the devices were not processed in order listed:

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md0 | grep active | sort -k 5
       0     259        0        0      active sync set-A   /dev/nvme0n1
       2     259        2        2      active sync set-A   /dev/nvme2n1
       1     259        4        1      active sync set-B   /dev/nvme4n1
       3     259        6        3      active sync set-B   /dev/nvme6n1
```

This example may be too simple for a generalized answer, my appologies.  In reality there could be many more devices from each array to be mirrored as described above.

Is there a correct way to structure my command so that the order is guaranteed?